# How to make this LC3 program multiply instead?

Tags: loops, math, assembly, ascii, lc3

Was trying to learn how to multiply in LC3 but having trouble modifying my old program that was just meant for adding sums. How would I go about modifying this program to multiply by the 2 given inputs?
Code:

````
.ORIG x3000 ; begin at x3000

; input two numbers

IN ;input an integer character (ascii) {TRAP 23}

LD R3, HEXN30 ;subtract x30 to get integer

ADD R0, R0, R3

ADD R1, R0, x0 ;move the first integer to register 1

IN ;input another integer {TRAP 23}

ADD R0, R0, R3 ;convert it to an integer

; add the numbers

ADD R2, R0, R1 ;add the two integers

; print the results

LEA R0, MESG ;load the address of the message string

PUTS ;"PUTS" outputs a string {TRAP 22}

  ADD R0, R2, x0 ;move the sum to R0, to be output

  LD R3, HEX30 ;add 30 to integer to get integer character

  ADD R0, R0, R3

  OUT ;display the sum {TRAP 21}

     ; stop

HALT ;{TRAP 25}

; data

 MESG .STRINGZ "The sum of those two numbers is: "

 HEXN30 .FILL xFFD0 ; -30 HEX

 HEX30 .FILL x0030 ; 30 HEX

.END```
````

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach to multiply on LC-3 is repetitive addition.  So keep summing the multiplicand and decrement the multiplier; the iteration stops when the multiplier is consumed (i.e. zero).

There are lot's of caveats: if the multiplier is negative, then we would either negate it to use with count down, or count up instead — either way, the final result would be negated.

Since multiplication is commutative, we might consider using the lessor (absolute) value for the multiplier so that fewer iterations are done.  But for more optimal multiplication, we would switch to a whole 'nother algorithm, the [shift and add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Shift_and_add).  Note that this algorithm is usually presented for hardware implementation, in which saving precious register bits is important, whereas for software this is not a really significant concern.